# Variant in Quran 18:79-80

Tags: uloom-al-quran

Can someone explain this variant:

We read in Bukhari 4448:

> قال سعيد بن جبير فكان ابن عباس يقرأ وكان أمامهم ملك يأخذ كل سفينة
> صالحة غصباوكان يقرأ وأما الغلام فكان كافرا وكان أبواه مؤمنين‏. قال
> سعيد بن جبير فكان ابن عباس يقرأ وكان أمامهم ملك يأخذ كل سفينة  صالحة
> غصباوكان يقرأ وأما الغلام فكان كافرا و كان أبواه مؤمنين‏.‏‏‏‏
>
> Sayd bin Jubayr narrated that Ibn Abbas used to recite: ‘And in front
> (ahead) of them there was a king who used to seize every serviceable
> boat by force’. and used to recite: “and as for the boy he was a
> disbeliever and his parents were believers”

Comment: Can you elaborate? What's there to explain?

Comment: @TheZ whether Ibn Abbas was reciting a different Harf, an abrogated verse or if this was a recitation with tafsir.

Comment: It's not an abrogated verse obviously since it's in the Quran in different wording. The apparent is that it is another harf.

Comment: @TheZ your statement needs clarification..

Answer (score 1):

This word ( serviceable صالحة ) is Mansukh (was not in the final revise of Quran Jebreel and the Prophet recited twice in the last Ramadan of the Prophet's life ﷺ) the written in mushaf now does not have that word. The companions wrote the Quran as per that last presentation.

All that was revealed of Quran is from Allah and all is there in (Om Alkitab, or Lawh Al Mahfouth)

You can read more about the subject Nasikh and Mansukh.

Allah says:
**۞ مَا نَنسَخْ مِنْ آيَةٍ أَوْ نُنسِهَا نَأْتِ بِخَيْرٍ مِّنْهَا أَوْ مِثْلِهَا ۗ أَلَمْ تَعْلَمْ أَنَّ اللَّهَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدِيرٌ (106)**

> If We ever abrogate a verse or cause it to be forgotten, We replace it with a better or similar one. Do you not know that Allah is Most Capable of everything? [2:106](https://quran.com/2:106?font=v1&translations=20%2C131)

And says:

**وَمَا كَانَ لِرَسُولٍ أَنْ يَأْتِيَ بِآيَةٍ إِلَّا بِإِذْنِ اللَّهِ لِكُلِّ أَجَلٍ كِتَابٌ * يَمْحُو اللَّهُ مَا يَشَاءُ وَيُثْبِتُ وَعِنْدَهُ أُمُّ الْكِتَابِ**

> It was not for any messenger to bring a sign without Allah’s permission. Every destined matter has a ˹set˺ time. (38) Allah eliminates and confirms what He wills, and with Him is the Master Record. (39)  (13:38-39)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite evidently a variant of said verses.

As the hadith tells that Ibn Abbas *recited* alike, it is also quite clear that he considered it a part of the Qur'an.

The hadith does not relate whether this version is erroneous, abrogated or an equally valid variant. The reason that the hadith was related was the observation of the difference so that the difference can't be only due to an imprecise transmission of the hadith.

We know that the prophet received variant versions of which he did not decide that either of them was wrong.

By faith we believe that God guided those who compiled the final version of the Qur'an so that we consider the version we read the reliable one.